# Why am I receiving notifications about empty review queues?

Tags: bug, support, user-interface, notifications

I've noticed that I very frequently see the red dot appear on the navbar link to review queues, but when I click on it there are no queues that need any attention. This seems to happen almost every day, sometimes multiple times per day.

Is this a weird timing issue where somebody else is consistently reviewing an item before I'm able to get to it, or is it some weird bug in Stack Exchange?

[image: red dot on top bar review icon]

Comment: I noticed this happening when I submit a suggested edit to a tag wiki. I wonder if that's the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are outstanding things to approve that you don't yet have the reputation to do (such as a tag wiki edit), it'll still give you the red dot, unfortunately.

Comment: That's it then. I'm seeing the red dot as a result of my own activity on the site.